# tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Getting an error with table view `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` message sent to *deallocated instance*. With local webservice it is working well. But it is not working with live webservice.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TreasureModel *data=[[TreasureModel alloc]init];
    data=[self.treasureData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    treasureID=[NSString stringWithFormat:data.Id];
}
```

`TreasureModel` contains two fields: `Id` and `name`.

`TreasureData` holds an object of `TreasureModel`.

Comment: You should probably post at least the code of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{                                        TreasureModel *data=[[TreasureModel alloc]init];
      data=[self.treasureData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];          
    
    treasureID=  [NSString stringWithFormat: data.Id]  }  TreasureModel contains two fields Id and name. treasuredata holds and object of TreasureModel.

Comment: I copied the code to your question - hopefully this will stop downvoting :) How is `treasureID` defined? As an iVar or property of `self` - by `self` i mean the object holding `treasureData`? What are thy types of `Id` and `name`?

Comment: I think you should try this instead:  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", data.Id]; It expects a format string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this into answer instead of comment for readability sake.

It looks that the only purpose of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is to store `data.Id` into `treasureID`. And it looks that `treasureID` is an `iVar` of `NSString *` type.

You don't say what kind of type `TreasureModel.Id` is, so here are variant for `NSString` and `NSInteger`.

If `TreasureModel.Id` is `NSString *`, you could use:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TreasureModel *data=(TreasureModel *)[self.treasureData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    treasureID=[NSString stringWithString: data.Id];
}
```

If it's `NSInteger`, try:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TreasureModel *data=(TreasureModel *)[self.treasureData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    treasureID=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",data.Id];
}
```

If this doesn't work we're gonna have to look for the problem elswhere in the code.